# Extract output of subquery inside UNNEST () and pass to outer main query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am  having a difficult time extracting a value from a subquery which is inside UNNEST().

The inner subquery provides distinct values of a given column .
The outer is then suppose to generate the string based on each input column from subquery.

Example : Inner query output has 4 distinct values like a1, a2, a3, a4.

The outer query output should be a concatenation of multiple string and generate output as

```
MAX(IF(KEY="a1", VALUE, null)) a1, 
MAX(IF(KEY="a2", VALUE, null)) a2,
MAX(IF(KEY="a3", VALUE, null)) a3, 
MAX(IF(KEY="a4", VALUE, null)) a4
```

Query :

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
'''SELECT  ''' || ( STRING_AGG("MAX(IF(KEY = '" || x.value || " ', _KEY, NULL))  AS " || x.value ) ) || '''
FROM UNNEST((SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT( KEY, 5) FROM `project.dataset.table` )) x
'''
```

Error : Query error: Unrecognized name: x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below should do the trick

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
'''SELECT  ''' || (
  SELECT STRING_AGG("MAX(IF(key = '" || x.key || "', value, NULL))  AS " || x.key ) 
  FROM `project.dataset.table` x
  JOIN UNNEST((SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT( key, 5) FROM `project.dataset.table` )) y
  ON x.key = y.value
  ) || '''
FROM `project.dataset.table`
'''
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Is there any other way to solve this instead of calling the table thrice. The output i wanted to achieve can be done with the outer query namely x also. Can't the output of subquery inside UNNEST() be used as an input to outer query without putting join()